# Models from stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am writing an application where I'm using code first design. The models returned from stored procedures do not map directly to an entity from the database.

The issue I am having is while I'm inheriting from an interface on each entity, I'm unable to use these custom models:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'CategoryDetailEntity' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToArrayAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Here is the code in my context file:

```
// Shouldn't be in the database, this is pulled from a stored procedure
public DbSet<Entities.CustomEntities.CategoryDetailEntity> CategoryDetailEntities { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Exclude models that are not bound to a table
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.CustomEntities.CategoryDetailEntity>().ToTable(nameof(CategoryDetailEntities), t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
}
```

The entity code:

```
[NotMapped]
public partial class CategoryDetailEntity : CategoryEntity
{
    public int NumProducts { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryEntity:

```
[Table("Category")]
public partial class CategoryEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public CategoryEntity Parent { get; set; } = null;
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

The base entity has the ID, Created By / Date, Modified By / Date.

---

Solution:

@JohnM was able to lead me to the solution.  I had two issues.

1. I tried to create a base service class in which my Database models were using. This was the same in my WebAPI, where in the Startup.cs file, I was only using the Base Service to do dependency injection:

   services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseService<>), typeof(BaseService<>));

This meant that the stored procedure was never being called first, only the base class of simple crud functionality.

Once I added all of the services layers explicitly, I was able to call the GetAll function from the correct service as intended.

```
public CategoryController(ICategoryService service, IMapper mapper) : base(service, mapper) {}
```

instead of

```
public CategoryController(IBaseService<CategoryDetailModel> service, IMapper mapper) : base(service, mapper) {}
```

2. The accepted Solution solved the other issue, in which using Code First, I wanted to make sure that the model from the Stored Procedure was not included in the migration.

In the Context.cs file:

```
// Shouldn't be in the database, this is pulled from a stored procedure
public DbSet<CategoryDetailModel> CategoryDetails { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     // Exclude models that are not bound to a table
     modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryDetailModel>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
}
```

Using this, I no longer had to mark the Model as [NotMapped]

```
public partial class CategoryDetailModel : BaseEntity
{
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public int NumProducts { get; set; }
    public ImageEntity Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: EF can project results on to a model.  It doesn't need to be an 'entity'.

Comment: If you're using code first, how do stored procedures come into play?

Comment: I tend to define a regular class to hold the results of a stored proc, and then define it as a keyless entity type in OnModelCreating(), e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<MyModelClass>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);`

Comment: @riwen They are in play since you want to return specific or aggregate data into one model.

Comment: @JohnM Please respond as the answer.  That helped to get me where I needed to be.  I'll explain in my original post what I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling stored procedures I define a regular class to hold the results - so one property for each column in the result set. I then define it as a [keyless entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations), so the following goes in the OnModelCreating() method of your database context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModelClass>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

Comment: See Original Post for Solution based on this answer.